# Possible to find velocity of person in video or camera using openpose

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, jupyter-notebook, gpu, openpose

Question is, I want to calculate the speed of my arm for Slap detection. So I am using openpose to get the body points (here total points: 25) using body_25 model and using this along with the time I want to deduce the speed of my arm, i googled through openpose, stackoverflow, github.But could not succeed?

Velocity = Distance / Time = dx/dt

dx = frame3_bodypoints - frame_1_bodypoints;
dt = ?

I don't know how to find this from the openpose, is there a way I can find this? Any thoughts, would be great help!

Comment: What's wrong with just using the speed of the hand (point 4 or 7)? dt is the time between frames and probably doesn't even matter all that much as long as the time between frames is roughly constant. For a slap, you're looking for an abrupt change of velocity, right?

Comment: @bfris: Thanks for the reply. Do you think difference between the frames is sufficient? Yes, looking for abrupt change in velocity.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used [OpenPose](https://cmu-perceptual-computing-lab.github.io/openpose/web/html/doc/). But Newtonian physics would indicate that a slap corresponds to a sudden change in velocity of the hand.

I think it's a reasonable first approximation to assume that the Δt between frames is constant. Instantaneous variation in frame rate is called [jitter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jitter). I would expect jitter to be small for modern recording devices. In any case, I don't know how to get instantaneous frame rate with the tools (OpenCV, PIL) that I am familiar with. I couldn't find any references to frame rate or time in the [OpenPose docs](https://cmu-perceptual-computing-lab.github.io/openpose/web/html/doc/).

For calculating velocity and delta-velocity, you have choices. Straight up linear velocity of the hand might be the easiest. For position changes use the geometric mean of positions (Δs = sqrt((x2-x1)^2 + (y2-y1)^2).

You could also calculate an angular velocity between the hand and the elbow, but that would be a little more involved and prone to noise.

Comment: Thanks for the reply: For linear velocity, is it like the object has to follow a specific straight line in terms of its movement? ref: https://www.vedantu.com/physics/linear-velocity

Comment: Maybe you don't care whether the velocity is linear or angular. Maybe just looking for a sudden change is enough to give you a slap signal. I would start with linear because it's easier to calculate. In any event, once you have a dataset, you can go nuts analyzing it different ways.